# writing a test to determine if code is being executed in parallel (future)

Tags: clojure

I have a piece of code which I run in parallel using a future -

```
(def services [s1 s2])

(defn get-data []
  (->>
   (map #(future
            (->> (p/fetch %)
                 (p/parse %)))
        services)
   (map deref)
   (apply concat)))

(get-data)
```

The requirement for the above piece of code is to run two services in parallel. So I want to create a test that determines if the function `(get-data)` runs code for both the services in parallel or not. How do write such a test?

Comment: Are you looking for a one-off REPL test or a repeatable unit test?  A one-off test typically consists of `println`s and `Thread/sleep`s in your worker functions.  A repeatable test would need to check for the state of reference types changing in the correct order.

Comment: @JohnJ I am looking for a repeatable test. Any ideas regarding it ?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt 's answer would probably be the place to start.  The only thing I'd add would be, you'd want to cancel the threads once the two starts were recorded, for best test performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an agent to record the start and stop events into a sequence, then read the sequence to ensure that it contains at least two start events before the first stop event.

```
 (map #(future
          (send watcher conj :start)
          (let [result (->> (p/fetch %)
                            (p/parse %))]
            (send watcher conj :finish)
            result)))
```

or you can use `with-redefs` to wrap your fetch and parse functions to avoid mixing test and production code.